# DNS lookup works locally but won't go online

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone, dns-server

I had registered `amraei.com` 2 years ago. Recently hired a VPS and setup a DNS server using BIND to host it on my own server.

I installed **Webmin** and setup BIND 9 on CentOS 7. As the setup finished, when I use `dig` command on the server, the result is:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-29.el7_2.2 <<>> amraei.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 58019
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 4

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;amraei.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
amraei.com.     60  IN  A   87.236.214.26

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
amraei.com.     60  IN  NS  server.amraei.com.
amraei.com.     60  IN  NS  ns2.amraei.com.
amraei.com.     60  IN  NS  ns1.amraei.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
server.amraei.com.  60  IN  A   87.236.214.26
ns1.amraei.com.     60  IN  A   87.236.214.26
ns2.amraei.com.     60  IN  A   87.236.214.26
```

Th domain current DNS has been set to:

```
ns1.kassit.com 
ns2.kassit.com
```

After about 3 days, whenever I try to change DNS to `ns1.amraei.com` and `ns2.amraei.com` I get this error:

```
{ns2=NameServer ns2.amraei.com is not a valid Nameserver, ns1=NameServer ns1.amraei.com is not a valid Nameserver}
```

I checked `ns1.amraei.com` using http://dns.squish.net/ and the result was:

```
Summary
100% resulted in an error

Results
50.0% Refused at ns1.kassit.com (78.46.158.237)
50.0% Refused at ns2.kassit.com (78.46.158.237)
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should register your nameserver in registrar, and without the [glue record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records), your nameservers never work.